# I@49d67b41 prints when trying to print a 2d array

Tags: java

This is an unusual problem I have: I've created a 2d int array with dimensions of  3X3, no parameters and when I try to print it out on the screen it displays something like this : [[I@49d67b41. Any suggestions?

```
public static void main (String[]  args) {
    System.out.println(test2());
}

static int [][] test2 () {
    int [][] l = new int[3][3];
    return l;
}
```

Comment: What do you think it should print and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(test2));
```

Comment: Nope. You should use `Arrays.deepToString(test2)` in that specific case, as it's a 2d array. Otherwise it will print the same horrible string for each sub-array :)

Comment: +1 for being on the right lines. Better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`int[][]` is a subclass of type `Object`. The default `toString()` method is being called, and you're seeing the hex code of your object. You need to implement your own method for printing out the `int[][]` type.

**Example**

```
for(int[] values : test2()) {
    for(int value : values) {
         System.out.print(int + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```